# Can you use a boot disk with Anroid 4.1 Tablets

Tags: linux

I was wondering if you could give me steps (if even possible) as to how you would boot (ubuntu linux since Android is linux based) a flash drive on my Android Tablet. I currently run on an OTG capable Kocaso M736 with Android 4.1.1 with a Rockchip processor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't boot a boot disk for a PC on on Android device (which isn't a PC). If you want to install Ubuntu, Ubuntu needs to support your device, and if it does, you can find instructions and all the files you need to download on the Ubuntu website. Obviously as this is an Android site and not an Ubuntu site, we can't help you with Ubuntu installation, nor if your device isn't supported.

There's also an app "Ubuntu on Android" which gives you an Ubuntu userspace, but running as an app on top of Android. Again, we can't help you with that on this site.